# Get entity by name and create relationship using CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to create a relation between two entities Mensagem and Categories, but i'm getting the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: property = "mensagemParaCategorias"; desired type = NSSet; given type = __NSArrayI; ...
).'
```

What i tried to do was: Create a entity property (categoriaAtual), then try to get the entity by name and them set the entity to the fetched results and them create the relationship .

Here is my code.

createInitialDate.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Mensagens.h"
#import "Categorias.h"

@interface createInitialData : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic) Categorias *categoriaAtual;

-(void)createMessage:(NSString *)mensagem ComAutor:(NSString *)autor;
```

CreateInitialData.m

```
-(void)createMessage:(NSString *)mensagem ComAutor:(NSString *)autor {
    Mensagens *novaMensagem = (Mensagens *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Mensagens" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [novaMensagem setMensagem:mensagem];
    [novaMensagem setAutor:autor];
    NSDate *agora = [NSDate date];
    [novaMensagem setDataCriada:agora];
    [self categoria:@"Posts"];

    novaMensagem.mensagemParaCategorias = _categoriaAtual; // This is where i try to create the relation between the 2 entities. 

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;

    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error! %@", error);
    }

}



-(void)categoria:(NSString *)nomeCategoria {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];


    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Categorias" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categoria == '%@'", nomeCategoria];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self managedObjectContext]executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Problem! %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Objetos %@", fetchedObjects);
        _categoriaAtual = fetchedObjects;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mensagemParaCategorias
```

is a to-many relationship but you are assigning a pointer to an object that is not an instance of `NSSet`. Xcode has an option to generate methods on your managed object subclasses for adding objects to a to-many relationship.